# Joining multiple tables with single join clause (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

So I'm learning SQL (sqlite flavour) and looking through the [sqlite JOIN-clause documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/join-clause.html), I figure that these two statements are valid:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN (table2, table3) USING (id);
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 USING (id)
JOIN table3 USING (id)
```

(or even, but that's beside the point:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN (table 2 JOIN table3 USING id) USING id
```

)

Now I've seen the second one (chained join) a lot in SO questions on `JOIN` clauses, but rarely the first (grouped table-query). Both querys execute in SQLiteStudio for the non-simplified case.

A minimal example is provided [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1b97deb0d51e6f66007f45fdddc876cf) based on this code

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    field1 TEXT
)
WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    field2 TEXT
)
WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE TABLE table3 (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    field3 TEXT
)
WITHOUT ROWID;

INSERT INTO table1 (field1, id)
VALUES ('FOO0', 0),
       ('FOO1', 1),
       ('FOO2', 2),
       ('FOO3', 3);

INSERT INTO table2 (field2, id)
VALUES ('BAR0', 0),
       ('BAR2', 1),
       ('BAR3', 3);

INSERT INTO table3 (field3, id)
VALUES ('PIP0', 0),
       ('PIP1', 1),
       ('PIP2', 2);

SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN (table2, table3) USING (id);

SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 USING (id)
JOIN table3 USING (id);
```

Could someone explain why one would use one over the other and if they are not equivalent for certain input data, provide an example? The first certainly looks cleaner (at least less redundant) to me.

---

[INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause) has been suggested as a possible duplicate. While it touches on the use of `,` as a join operator, I feel the questions and especially the answers are more focussed on the readability aspect and use of `WHERE` vs `JOIN`. My question is more about the general validity and possible differences in outcome (given the necessary input to induce the difference).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: The first one certainly isn't allowed by the SQL standard, and I think the last one is invalid standard SQL as well

Comment: What did you learn running examples? What is "not happy"? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: Edit your post to clearly ask the 1 specific question you are trying to ask. Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of editing time. Adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear. PS My answer already tells you where they are not equivalent--in the example you gave. But you haven't run that actual code.

Comment: Added minimalistic example, which eliminates certain intrinsic assumptions made in the non-simplified example and reveals actual differences. I propose to close this question as I feel I cannot rephrase it in such a way that it becomes meaningful again. Thorsten's answer has been helpful but imo doesn't analyse the example provided in the question enough to justify an accept answer.

Comment: Accept just means an answer helped the most. Why not indicate that? You can change your accept any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not enforce a proper join syntax. It sees the join operator (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc., even the comma of the outdated 1980s join syntax) separate from the condition (`ON`, `USING`). That is not good, because it makes joins more prone to errors. The SQLite docs are hence a *very* bad reference for learning joins. (And SQLite itself a bad system for learning them, because the DBMS doesn't detect standard SQL join violations.)

Stick to the syntax defined by the SQL standard (and don't ever use comma-separated joins):

**FROM** table [alias]

((([**INNER**] | [(**LEFT**|**FULL**) [**OUTER**]]) **JOIN** table [alias] (**ON** conditions | **USING (** columns **)**)) | (**CROSS JOIN** table [alias]))

((([**INNER**] | [(**LEFT**|**FULL**) [**OUTER**]]) **JOIN** table [alias] (**ON** conditions | **USING (** columns **)**)) | (**CROSS JOIN** table [alias]))

...

(Hope, I've got this right :-) And I also hope this is readable enough :-| I've omitted `NATURAL JOIN` and `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN` here, because I don't recommend using them at all.)

For `table` you can place some table name or view or a subquery (the latter including parentheses, e.g. `(select * from mytable)`). Columns in `USING` have to be surrounded by parentheses (e.g. `USING (a, b, c)`). (You can of couse use parentheses around `ON` conditions as well, if you find this more readable.)

In your case, a properly written query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 USING (id)
JOIN table3 USING (id)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.id
```

for instance. The example suggests three 1:1 related tables, though. In real life these are extremely rare and a more typical example would be

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.t2_id = t2.id
```